# How to get a variable's value from a Java Bean in JSP using Expression Language?

Tags: jsp, javabeans, el

I have been looking around to get a variable's value that I am populating at the back end and display it in a JSP using Expression Language. I am not using servlets so I cannot call `.getParameter(){}` and it is also not part of URL. I am not sure enough if this is possible. Suppose I have the following bean.

```
public class Test {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String toString() {
    setName( "Expression Language" );
    return this.getName();
}
```

}

JSP

```
<div id="showName">
    <c:if test="${name != null}">
        <td class="fieldLabelBold" style="color:#0033CC" 
        align="center">${name}</td>
    </c:if>
</div>
```

Can I do something like above code snippet.

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a bean using your 'Test' class:

```
<jsp:useBean id="testBean" class="package.Test">
```

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_java_beans.htm) you can find a good tutorial about JSP (and beans)